# How to bind repeater in loop in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used repeater in asp.net

```
 <div class="slider-inner">
<div id="daslider" runat="server" class="da-slider">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSlider" runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Panel ID="sld" runat="server" class="da-slide">
            <h2><asp:Literal ID="lblTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h2>
            <p>
               <asp:Literal ID="lblDescription" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </p>
            <div class="da-img">
                 <iframe id="framevid" runat="server" visible="false" width="530" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                 <asp:Image ID="sldrimg" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="btnlinks" runat="server" class="da-arrows">
            <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
            <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
        </asp:Panel>

    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
       </div>
       </div>
```

In CS File I want to bind them programically using loop as below lines of code

```
private void GetMainAppSettings()
{ 
    MainSetting Item = context.FetchMainAppSettings();
    SliderContext contextSlider = new SliderContext();
    Slider SW = new Slider();
    string PageName = "Home Page";
    IEnumerable<_14Muslims.Domain.Entity.Slider> pType = contextSlider.SliderFetchAllEnabled(PageName);
    foreach (Slider item in pType)
    {
        lblTitle.Text = item.SliderTitle;
        lblDescription.Text = item.SliderDescription;
        framevid.Attributes.Add("src", item.SliderImage);
        sldr.Attributes.Add("src", item.SliderImage);
        daslider.Style.Add("background-image", WebUtility.UrlSchemeAuthority() + @"/FileStore/AppSettingsSiteLogos/" + item.BackgroundImage);

 }
 }
```

Note that GetMainAppSettings() is called on page_load event

Please Help me !!!

Comment: Just loop using repeateritems and populate the field controls.

Comment: Should `daslider` have as background the last loaded item? This way it's set over and over again for each item.

Comment: Check out my tutorial, see if that helps http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/20                         accidently added the comment to an answer hence the duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate things that you need to do:

1. Set the source of the repeater
2. Tell the repeater what to do for each item in the source.

To achieve the first, you just need to set the `DataSource` property of the repeater to the collection of items you need displayed, and execute a `DataBind` call:

```
private void GetMainAppSettings()
{ 
    MainSetting Item = context.FetchMainAppSettings();
    SliderContext contextSlider = new SliderContext();
    Slider SW = new Slider();
    string PageName = "Home Page";
    IEnumerable<_14Muslims.Domain.Entity.Slider> pType = contextSlider.SliderFetchAllEnabled(PageName);
    rptSlider.DataSource(pType);
    rptSlider.DataBind();
}
```

When this is done, the repeater will loop through each item, process it and, display whatever is needed. To customize this process, the repeated provides an [`ItemDataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event where you can set how the template should look for a specific item:

```
protected void rptSlider_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
      // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        //get the item from the event arguments
        var item = (Slider)e.Item.DataItem;
        //get the controls
        var lblTitle = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTitle");
        var lblDescription= (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription");
        var framevid= (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("framevid");
        var sldr= (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("sldr");
        //set the values
        lblTitle.Text = item.SliderTitle;
        lblDescription.Text = item.SliderDescription;
        framevid.Attributes.Add("src", item.SliderImage);
        sldr.Attributes.Add("src", item.SliderImage);
      }
   }
```

This will execute once for each item in the data source, and you have complete control over what goes where and how. The looping is done implicitly for you by the repeater itself.

Comment: `daslider` is not inside repeater it's outside

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal I've removed it, as the OP's intention is not clear from the question.

Comment: Check out my tutorial, see if that helps http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/20

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop the data in your code behind, you can directly assign the DataSource and `Repeater` control will take care of rest.

In Code behind, you can programatically set the DataSource like this:-

```
rptSlider.DataSource = pType;
rptSlider.DataBind();
```

In your repeater control, you can put the Data Binder code nuggets to assign particular properties to control like this:-

```
<h2><asp:Literal ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# SliderTitle%>'></asp:Literal></h2>
```

and so on..for other controls.

Answer (score 0):

Why use loop for bind repeater? You can directly assign your object "pType" to repeater data source. Like

```
 IEnumerable<_14Muslims.Domain.Entity.Slider> pType = contextSlider.SliderFetchAllEnabled(PageName);
 rptSlider.DataSource=pType;
 rptSlider.DataBind();
```

After you can access all your field in repeater on .aspx page.

More Details see below article:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: I have tried this code, it is working fine... Due to some important reason I have to use it in loop... Please help

Comment: Which reason so you can use loop?